# What is a proper way to approach the following scheduling task

Tags: scheduling, grouping, rules

I am thinking about the following scheduling problem:

1. I have `X` people.
2. I have `Y` meeting slots with `Z` meeting roles available in every meeting.
3. For some roles, same person may combine two of them in a single meeting, but most are one person = one role.
4. For each person `x` in `X`, I know a set of facts about them:
   a) The last date they attended the meeting and had a specific role (historical);
   b) Their availability for any meeting `y` in `Y`;
   c) Their specific preference for the roles `z` in `Z` or a set of roles (no specific dates) for the group of meetings.
5. I'd like to build a scheduler with the following objectives in mind:
   a) All meeting roles are filled.
   b) Preferences are accommodated if possible;
   c) Distribution of people / roles should be uniform (i.e. if one person is scheduled every meeting and other just for one meeting once in a while -- it's unacceptable; if one person is scheduled for the same role over, and over, and over again -- it's unacceptable).

Now, I have a gut feeling that the task is not easy at all :), so my specific questions are:

1. What language would be better suited for the task (somehow I feel Prolog can deal with it, but I am not entirely sure).
2. What is the proper approach to solve this task and how close can I get to my objectives in #4 above?
3. Any good read on the kind of problem I am looking to solve?

Thank you!

P.S. If you are curious, the use case is scheduling a roster for a set of Toastmasters meeting ([example](http://www.wellesley.edu/Activities/homepage/toastmasters/agenda.html)) (I am lazy do it by hand and I'd like computer to help me in this task at least partially).

Comment: With regard to _what language would be better suited for the task_, I assume you want to choose between prolog and Python, or are others also allowed? You don't mention it explicitly, but there is a Python tag that suggests this...

Comment: @jro, No, I am comfortable with different languages. Ultimately, I want to learn how to solve a problem like that, so I am willing to learn a language if it's a better suit for that type of tasks. Python and Prolog were the first ones that came to mind.

Comment: Maybe you just want to create something yourself (cheers for that), but in getting more information on what on earth "Toastmaster meetings" were, I ran across a [Club Management Software](http://www.toastmasters.org/ClubMgmt) page that already contains quite a list with software. Maybe that's also an option for you?

Comment: @jro In a nutshell, `Toastmasters` is an organization that helps people with public speaking skills. I am aware of that website but I am pretty sure the software they offer just helps you build a schedule in a specific format manually (i.e. you pick roles for people). My goal is to learn how to automate this task and probably learn more about this spectrum of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule engine, like **Drools Expert** or **Prolog** is good for *defining* the constraints (= score function). However it's terrible at *finding* the best solution.

Since your problem is probably *NP complete* (especially if the meetings need to be put into a timeslot and/or 1 person can't attend 2 meetings at the same time), you need to use a planning optimization algorithm on top of that, such as construction heuristics and metaheuristics. Take a look at the curriculum course example in **[Drools Planner](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.CR1/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html)** (java, open source, ASL).

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the language you are going to program in doesn't really matter that much: for simple problems the language to use is more of a personal preference instead of an exact science. If you like/want to learn Python, use that. If you "feel like" Prolog today, use that.

What will be a factor in your choice though is how you want to preserve and present your data. From your question it can be told that you need the following:

- A database (or at least, a persistent resource) to store your available participants and roles, past and future meetings storing the roles for every participant, and some way to schedule availability.
- Some way to present your data (command line, GUI, or website).
- Some business logic that describes the way of assigning roles, criteria for the attendance and such.

You will want to use some third-party components for most of these, since your time is to be spent on the added value of your product; creating a shiny ORM or GUI toolkit is not your goal in this. So the programming language you will choose should have a proper support for these items (especially the first two). I can't say it for Prolog, but Python will have you fully covered in these areas. I think it goes beyond the scope of this question to suggest specific toolkits, so I'll leave it at that for now.

After this step, you analyze your problem, which you seem to have done quite nicely already. So, start implementing it. To be able to verify your specific use cases, it sounds like you could benefit from some Test or Behavior Driven Design, so you may want to read up on that.

For learning the language, just search StackOverflow for "[language] tutorial": there are already plenty of answers linking to very nice resources for getting started with any language you will choose.

Final advice: perseverance is the hardest part, so try to set yourself some goals or milestones, or try to involve other people in one way or another. That way you'll enlarge the possibility of following through with creating a nice piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

1. Even though I'm a Python fan, I'd hardly suggest Prolog for this task. I'm familiar with Prolog, and it's definitely nicer solved with Prolog. But it depends on how you will use that program. Your choice - decide whether the installation of Python or Prolog is easier for you (if you just run it on your local PC, it doesn't matter that much I guess), or on other requirements you have.
2. It's farly simple with Prolog, if you know about Prolog. After you learnt Prolog, you can solve it with some thinking without much problems I guess (if you really understood Prolog!).
3. Basicly you should start with Prolog of course. I'd suggest to use SWI-Prolog, it's one of the most common Prolog Implementations used. Also, there is a nice tutorial for it: http://www.learnprolognow.org/

It seems to me, but I'm not 100% sure, that you are not familiar with Prolog yet. You need the time to learn Prolog first, so it also depends on how fast you need to have your program. It's possible to get through the Tutorial in less than a month, as far as I remember. Of course this hardly depends on how much time you invest per day - you can do it in less or even more time.

Prolog is based on rules. Every of your requirement can be expressed as a rule. After you have your set of rules, you can ask, which combination (of persons and meeting room) conform to all those rules. For the historical data of the different persons, you could use a small database.

Comment: I am familiar with the prolog in the capacity of university programming languages course could provide. Not much, but not completely nothing. So /why/ is Prolog a better fit exactly?

Comment: Prolog is a logical programming languages - a scheduling task can be solved with basic logic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with people who suggest Prolog for this task; I would suggest to take a look
at ECLiPSe (it is, besides being a Prolog implementation, a constraint programming 
language which have more powerful problem solving capabilities than just Prolog).
ECLiPSe has now a very nice introduction, with many examples and very to the point,
with a free pdf, written by Antoni Niederlinski:

http://www.anclp.pl/

Among the examples on ECLiPSe site, I found the following which seems to be relevant: http://eclipseclp.org/examples/roster.ecl.txt.

ECLiPSe is thoroughly documented and, according to this documentation, 
can be also integerated with C++/Java.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an optimization problem and I agree with Geoffrey that it would be a NP Complete problem. I recently developed a scheduling algorithm for a university that does final exam scheduling. I used a genetic algorithm with domain specific heuristics to solve that problem. My implementation performed nicely with a student count of 3000 + and course count of 500, it took about 2 hours to find a near optimal solution.